# How to make a text disappear for mouseout in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was looking for an answer all over the website but nothing helps, I hope you guys will find the solution for me because it seems I can't :D I am really-really new at JS (and JQuery) so my code may seem dumb/too simple for lots of you

I have 5 different img-s (1 class for all, 1 container for the 5 imgs) and 5 different span-s (5 different ID-s and 1 class).
On mouseover I did 5 functions so when I move my mouse over the img the proper text appears. Great.

But I would like to make the text disappear on mouseout.
I am sure I can solve it calling that one class (.text), but I don't know how.
Any ideas? :)

I am over the "toggle", "for", "if" orders but nothing seems to help.
Thank you in advance :)

```js
function aboutme() {
  document.getElementById("aboutme-text").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function classtypes() {
  document.getElementById("classtypes-text").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
.text {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e75b00;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: inline;
}

#aboutme-text {
  margin-left: 70px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#classtypes-text {
  margin-left: 280px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="DT1" onMouseOver="aboutme()" onMouseOut="disappear()">
  <img src="assets/images/aboutme-1.jpg" alt="RÓLAM" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<div id="DT2" onMouseOver="classtypes()" onMouseOut="disappear()">
  <img src="assets/images/classtypes-1.jpg" alt="ÓRATÍPUSOK" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<span class="text" id="aboutme-text">RÓLAM</span>
<span class="text" id="classtypes-text">ÓRATÍPUSOK</span>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet  - you are missing "disappear"

Comment: I would suggest to add eventlisteners to a container instead of inline event handlers

Comment: Yes I didn't put here all the not-working ones :)

Comment: Like this?
`let texts = document.getElementById("$=-text");

            let img = document.getElementsByClassName("desktopimg");

            img.addEventListener("mouseout", function disappear(){
                texts.style.visibility = "hidden"                
            })`

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64899725/295783) for a more elegant way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're attempting?

I simply added your disappear function and simply applied `hidden` to each div.

Run the snippet below.

```js
function aboutme() {
  document.getElementById("aboutme-text").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function classtypes() {
  document.getElementById("classtypes-text").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function disappear() {
  document.getElementById("classtypes-text").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("aboutme-text").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.text {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e75b00;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: inline;
}

#aboutme-text {
  margin-left: 70px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#classtypes-text {
  margin-left: 280px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="DT1" onmouseover="aboutme()" onmouseout="disappear()">
  <img src="assets/images/aboutme-1.jpg" alt="RÓLAM" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<div id="DT2" onmouseover="classtypes()" onmouseout="disappear()">
  <img src="assets/images/classtypes-1.jpg" alt="ÓRATÍPUSOK" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<span class="text" id="aboutme-text">RÓLAM</span>
<span class="text" id="classtypes-text">ÓRATÍPUSOK</span>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers are not recommended. Also not very DRY

Comment: GOSH I did not think of make more than one order in a function -- I was doing almost everything but not the simpliest. Thank you very much, it works! :)

Comment: @mplungjan I agree, however, OP is very new and I thought it best to use the code from the example provided and not obfuscate that code to something else entirely. Additionally, yes, in most cases being as DRY as possible is great but in my opinion, DRY is not always the best answer, especially while you are new and in the process of learning.

Answer (score 1):

In your code was missing `disappear()` function.

In the same way as I did the "disappear()" function, you can also make the function to display the text. In a sense, you can use an argument. The argument is the ID of the element you want to hide

```js
function aboutme() {
    document.getElementById("aboutme-text").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function classtypes() {
    document.getElementById("classtypes-text").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function disappear(x) {
    document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.text {
    color: #dfdfdf;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e75b00;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline;
}

#aboutme-text {
    margin-left: 70px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#classtypes-text {
    margin-left: 280px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="DT1" onMouseOver="aboutme()" onMouseOut="disappear('aboutme-text')">
    <img src="assets/images/aboutme-1.jpg" alt="RÓLAM" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<div id="DT2" onMouseOver="classtypes()" onMouseOut="disappear('classtypes-text')">
    <img src="assets/images/classtypes-1.jpg" alt="ÓRATÍPUSOK" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<span class="text" id="aboutme-text">RÓLAM</span>
<span class="text" id="classtypes-text">ÓRATÍPUSOK</span>
```

---

**It will be more convenient if you use "EventListener"**

This script puts "EventListener" on all elements with class `link`

In the `data-id` attribute, enter the ID of the target element.

No need to change the script... just enter the attributes of the elements and the script will do everything else itself

**Example:**

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
    });

    links[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
}
```

```css
.text {
    color: #dfdfdf;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e75b00;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline;
}

#aboutme-text {
    margin-left: 70px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#classtypes-text {
    margin-left: 280px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="DT1" class="link" data-id="aboutme-text">
    <img src="assets/images/aboutme-1.jpg" alt="RÓLAM" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<div id="DT2" class="link" data-id="classtypes-text">
    <img src="assets/images/classtypes-1.jpg" alt="ÓRATÍPUSOK" class="desktopimg">
</div>

<span class="text" id="aboutme-text">RÓLAM</span>
<span class="text" id="classtypes-text">ÓRATÍPUSOK</span>
```

Comment: This is not very DRY.

Comment: wow good, thank you :) I used the 3rd answer because its simplier but I guess there is a situation when this will help more

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to delegate

I added the class `hide` to the spans and wrapped the links in a div

I use the [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) method of the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to set or remove the hide class

```js
const overout = e => { // one function to rule them all
  let tgt = e.target; // the `e` passed is the event(s) listened to. Here mouseover AND mouseout
  if (tgt.classList.contains("desktopimg")) tgt = tgt.closest(".link"); // if what is mousedover is the image, point to the div
  if (tgt.classList.contains("link")) { // here we have the div in the tgt - we check it is class="link"
    document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.id).classList.toggle("hide", e.type === "mouseout"); // toggle the class using the test for event type - mouseout, add class "hide" mouseover remove it 
  }
};
["mouseover","mouseout"] // the events we are interested in - we could add touchstart for mobiles for example
  .forEach(eventType => document.getElementById("container")  // the container we want to monitor
    .addEventListener(eventType, overout)); // add the listener for the eventType
```

```css
.text {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e75b00;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: inline;
}

#aboutme-text {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#classtypes-text {
  margin-left: 280px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="DT1" class="link" data-id="aboutme-text">
    <img src="assets/images/aboutme-1.jpg" alt="RÓLAM" class="desktopimg">
  </div>

  <div id="DT2" class="link" data-id="classtypes-text">
    <img src="assets/images/classtypes-1.jpg" alt="ÓRATÍPUSOK" class="desktopimg">
  </div>
</div>
<span class="text hide" id="aboutme-text">RÓLAM</span>
<span class="text hide" id="classtypes-text">ÓRATÍPUSOK</span>
```

Comment: I need more time (and knowledge) to unwrap your answer but I appreciate, thank you :)

Comment: @Katalin The other anwers are not "DRY" (don't repeat yourself) and are adding s multitude of event handlers to the DOM (document object model) when one is enough. I will comment on some of the statements I made. the code above is DRY, readable, and using as many best practices as possible